# How do i use a template file for my content type?

Tags: routes, nodes

quite new to drupal here so forgive me if things seems evident for you.
i'm building onto an already existing site in drupal 7. the site is a onepager frontpage and from the frontpage there are links to various content types.
now i created a new content type named article.
when i link to such an article from the frontpage i (arrive at an article and) cannot go back to the frontpage through the menu anymore, while it does work with the other content types. I have searched and searched and made sure every setting is the same as the other content types but the links just don't work (they do nothing).
I did see in the templates folder that there are template files for each content type except the one i made. I'm wondering if that is the problem? If so, i don't know what exactly to do to keep it working though. I duplicated a template file and renamed it after node-article.tpl.php, but i guess it doesn't suffice.
can anyone assist?

Thx

Comment: "i cannot go back to the frontpage through the menu anymore," - how so? menu item disappears? Or you click but nothing happens? Or what exactly?

Comment: What is href in both situations? What's in browser's console?...

Comment: the menu items are still there so there's nothing wrong with the menu in itself, it's just that when i click on a menu-item when i'm at content-type a, it takes me back to the frontpage. When i click on that same menu-item in content-type b (which i created), nothing happens. I checked everything and cannot see the difference between content-type a and b, except that there are template files for a and not for b. Sadly i don't know in which direction to look, i lack someunderstanding of how drupal works, but i'm learning it. Hope this track helps me find the answer quicker. thx

Comment: that's just it, the href stays exactly the same, in both conditions. When i click on the link in the element inspector, it works just fine, but it doesn't when i click on the actual link

Comment: You claim you checked everything, so please share info i asked for in my prev comment.

Comment: Console says: Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id. sdk.js:56
FB.init has already been called - this could indicate a problem sdk.js:56
Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id.

Comment: i seem to be spotting the problem (thanks to the console i apparently missed): i have this module 'ShareThis' installed and apparently the console error has something to do with Facebook. I disabled it and the error messages above are gone but the menu still doesn't work. Now i get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Comment: So it is about javascripts you are using. Sorry, but I doubt we can really help. If there are *your* JS, post them and maybe? If it is a bug, it will not be too good. I'm glad you at least found about / got reminded about console. Pretty useful tool, isn't it?

Comment: Thx Molot, at least you reminded me about the console which i totally forgot about, a very useful tool indeed. I'll search for an answer and maybe try and post my question in a js-related forum.

Answer (score 0):

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  print_r($variables['theme_hook_suggestions']);
}
```

put this code into you template.php this will give you the suggestions to make your tpl file.

And for your answer you just can print anything in you page.tpl.php file it prints then you just have to change in your page.tpl.php file

Comment: I don't think this answers the question in question's *body*. Sadly, question is bit ambiguous.

Comment: i know, i have this problem with expressing what i mean when i don't exactly know what i'm talking about;)

Answer (score 0):

just for the record, i found the problem. Apparently i needed to tell the main.js to check on the current page if it contained a certain string. If it didn't it could go back to the frontpage. I just needed to add that bit of code for that content type: `if(window.location.href.indexOf("customercase") == -1 && window.location.href.indexOf("jobs") == -1 && window.location.href.indexOf("article") == -1)`